# How to create an empty DOCTYPE using W3C DOM in Java?

Tags: java, xml, dom, doctype

I am trying to read an XML document and output it into a new XML document using the [W3C DOM API in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/package-summary.html). To handle DOCTYPEs, I am using the following code (from an input Document `doc` to a target File `target`):

```
TransformerFactory transfac = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer trans = transfac.newTransformer();
trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no"); // omit '<?xml version="1.0"?>'
trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

// if a doctype was set, it needs to persist
if (doc.getDoctype() != null) {
    DocumentType doctype = doc.getDoctype();
    trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.DOCTYPE_SYSTEM, doctype.getSystemId());
    trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.DOCTYPE_PUBLIC, doctype.getPublicId());
}

FileWriter sw = new FileWriter(target);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(sw);
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
trans.transform(source, result);
```

This works fine for both XML documents with and without DOCTYPEs. However, I am now coming across a `NullPointerException` when trying to transform the following input XML document:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE permissions >
<permissions>
  // ...
</permissions>
```

HTML 5 uses a similar syntax for its DOCTYPEs, [and it is valid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Type_Declaration#HTML5_DTD-less_DOCTYPE). But I have no idea how to handle this using the W3C DOM API - trying to set the `DOCTYPE_SYSTEM` to `null` throws an exception. Can I still use the W3C DOM API to output an empty doctype?

Answer (score 5):

Although this question is two years old, it is a top search result in some web search engine, so maybe it is a useful shortcut. See the question [Set HTML5 doctype with XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387127/set-html5-doctype-with-xslt) referring to http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/syntax.html#doctype-legacy-string, which says:

> For the purposes of HTML generators that cannot output HTML markup
>   with the short DOCTYPE "`<!DOCTYPE html>`", a **DOCTYPE legacy
>   string** may be inserted into the DOCTYPE [...]
>
> In other words, `<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">` or
>   `<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM 'about:legacy-compat'>`, case-insensitively
>   except for the part in single or double quotes.

Leading to a line of Java code like this:

```
trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.DOCTYPE_SYSTEM, "about:legacy-compat");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the suggestions here https://stackoverflow.com/a/6637886/116509. Basically it looks like it can't be done with standard Java DOM support.

You can also try StAX

```
    XMLStreamWriter xmlStreamWriter =
        XMLOutputFactory.newFactory().createXMLStreamWriter( System.out, doc.getXmlEncoding() );
    Result result = new StAXResult( xmlStreamWriter );
    // ... create dtd String 
    xmlStreamWriter.writeDTD( dtd );
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource( doc );
    trans.transform( source, result );
```

but it's ugly because the DTD parameter is a `String`, and you only have a `DocumentType` object.

Comment: I was also thinking of hacking around the FileWriter to write the XML prolog and the empty doctype, followed by the XML document `transform` without the XML prolog.