# Parsing xml with DOM, !ENTITY reference is deleted

Tags: java, xml, dom

I wanted to load  external subfiles using ENTITY attribute of XML. I did it using following procedure.

```
<!DOCTYPE doc [
<!ENTITY A SYSTEM "C:///XML//A.xml">
<!ENTITY B SYSTEM "C://XML//B.xml">
<!ENTITY C SYSTEM "C://CONFIGURATION//XML//C.xml">
]>

<list idPrefix="N" seqIdLength="5">
   &A;

 </list>
```

Then in xml, I am referencing these entries using  &. And  XML goes A.xml and reads each xml element from this file.  But if I want to modify this main xml from java, I have problem.First of all, DOCTYPE is deleted. 
For erased DOCTYPE  problem, I changed my xml in following format.

```
<!DOCTYPE doc SYSTEM "C://XML//test.dtd">
```

I have copied following lines into test.dtd.

```
<!ENTITY A SYSTEM "C:///XML//A.xml">
<!ENTITY B SYSTEM "C://XML//B.xml">
<!ENTITY C SYSTEM "C://CONFIGURATION//XML//C.xml">
```

When I save XML , Now DOCTYPE is not deleted. But I have another problem. Instead of &A reference, content of A file is inserted main xml, and with a reference to ENTITY path.

```
     <list idPrefix="N" seqIdLength="5">
  <alist name = "1" xml:base="file:///C://XML//A.xml"/>
  <alist name = "2" xml:base="file:///C://XML//A.xml"/>
  <alist name = "3" xml:base="file:///C://XML//A.xml"/>
  <alist name = "4" xml:base="file:///C://XML//A.xml"/>
  <alist name = "5" xml:base="file:///C://XML//A.xml"/>
  <alist name = "6" xml:base="file:///C://XML//A.xml"/>
  <alist name = "7" xml:base="file:///C://XML//A.xml"/>

 </list>
```

And now I have lost functionality of ENTITY . I have all data in main xml. Do we have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used same approach that told in following link [Parsing xml with DOM, DOCTYPE gets erased](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637076/parsing-xml-with-dom-doctype-gets-erased)

```
DOMImplementationLS domImplementationLS =
(DOMImplementationLS) dom.getImplementation().getFeature("LS","3.0");
LSOutput lsOutput = domImplementationLS.createLSOutput();
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("output.xml");
lsOutput.setByteStream((OutputStream) outputStream);
LSSerializer lsSerializer = domImplementationLS.createLSSerializer();
lsSerializer.write(dom, lsOutput);
outputStream.close();
```

But I can not modify values from sub file. I do not know this is logical.