# How to quiet org.w3c.dom.Document?

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have the following Java method:

```
private static Document documentFromFile(final File xmlFile)
{
    Document document = null;
    try
    {
        DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
            .newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory
            .newDocumentBuilder();
        document = docBuilder.parse(xmlFile);
        document.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    }
    catch(Exception exc)
    {
        // Handle exception...
    }

    return document;
}
```

In my test methods, if I pass this method a malformed XML file I get all sorts of error output on my console:

> [Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
>
> [Fatal Error] :1:1: Premature end of file.

I assume the culprit is `docBuilder.parse(xmlFile)`. I'd like to be able to disable this default output and "silence" the document builder, and I don't see any setter methods on this object that allow me to do anything like that. Do I have an remedies here or am I stuck with this?

Comment: Which [implementation](http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/org.w3c.dom.Document) of DOM manipulation library are we talking about? And what version? DocumentBuilderFactory has a setAttribute method, but you have to know what property name to set.

Comment: See if apply to you: ["how to disable dtd at runtime in java's xpath?"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/243728/1322198) and ["How can I ignore DTD validation but keep the Doctype when writing an XML file?"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/582352/1322198)

Comment: I'm using `javax.xml.parsers.*` for the lib and am using XSD schema validation...

Answer (score 3):

Use [DocumentBuilder.setErrorHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html#setErrorHandler%28org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler%29) to set an implementation of `ErrorHandler`. Don't be confused by the package name. Even though it says "org.xml.sax" it is they one you want. I think you can just use DefaultHandler because the Javadoc says that it ignores errors and warnings. If it is still too verbose, you can just supply your own implementation.

```
DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
db.setErrorHandler(new DefaultHandler());
```